# Board encoding in Tesauro's TD-Gammon

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, reinforcement-learning

Currently I am trying to get Tesauro's TD gammon to working. However I am a bit confused about how the board is encoded for input into the neural network.

I understand that he used 4 units per point on the board for each player (2 * 96 units), each two additional units for checkers on the bar and borne-off checkers (2 * 2 units) as well as two units indicating whose turn it is. That gives a total of 198 inputs. I also fully understand how to encode different numbers of checkers per point.

What I am not really sure of however, is the sequence of inputs. Is it that the 96 first inputs encode white checkers on the board, followed by two inputs for the white bar and borne-off checkers; and are the remaining inputs dedicated to black checkers, black bar, black off and the two units for indicating current player?

Or is rather that 4 successive input units encode one point of the board for one color, the next 4 input units encode the same point but now for the other player?

I´d be very glad if someone had some knowledge to share, since everything I found on the web is pretty ambiguous in terms of which input sequence Tesauro used to encode a particular backgammon situation.

Cheers,
Stephan

Comment: Are you trying to match TD gammon's exact feature encoding? IMO, you can probably drive yourself a bit crazy trying to match a feature encoding from several decades ago, when it's well known that other neural networks work better with different encodings.  My suggestion is that you use a board representation that implements the game correctly (or develop your own) and then try different feature encodings from that board representation.  Note that I'm not downplaying Tesauro's contribution to backgammon AI in the least bit.

Comment: Firstly, thanks for the quick answer Chris! I want to use TD gammon as a benchmark for a more sophisticated reinforcement learning approach that was developed in the lab I am working in. So I thought it was a good idea to stay as close as possible to Tesauro's version. But I guess it's always good to go through some trial-and-error.

Comment: No problem, BTW, even if you can't replicate the exact feature encoding that TD Gammon used, you can still pick an encoding that's close enough and then compare your proposed reinforcement learning approach against  the [temporal difference paradigm used by TD Gammon](http://www.bkgm.com/articles/tesauro/tdl.html) for that same set of features.  At least it will be an apples to apples comparison.

Comment: A foot note to this is that Gerald did publish a small benchmark program called `pubeval` about 20 years ago. He developed it at the time to be a benchmark for comparing other nets. It has a very basic encoding for the board. The source code was made available on rec.games.backgammon in this [article](http://www.bkgm.com/rgb/rgb.cgi?view+610). We keep a slightly revised one in the GNUBG NN source code tree [here](http://cvs.savannah.gnu.org/viewvc/gnubg-nn/gnubg/pub_eval.c?revision=1.2&root=gnubg&view=markup)

Comment: Thank you for the additional info! Might come in handy for evaluating my version of TD gammon first against a "weaker" opponent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in [this article about the details of TD Gammon](http://www.bkgm.com/articles/tesauro/tdl.html#h2:understanding_learning):

> In preliminary experiments, the input representation only encoded the raw board information (the number of White or Black checkers at each location), and did not utilize any additional pre-computed features relevant to good play, such as, e.g., the strength of a blockade or probability of being hit. These experiments were completely knowledge-free in that there was no initial knowledge built in about how to play good backgammon. In subsequent experiments, a set of handcrafted features (the same set used by Neurogammon) was added to the representation, resulting in higher overall performance.

It seems clear that there were a number of different version of TD Gammon, and none really defines a concrete version of TD Gammon. It seems that it did well with a raw board encoding, and even better when some handcrafted features were added.

Thus, it's probably somewhat of a wild goose chase to pin down the exact features, and it's probably not what you want anyway. You could compare, for a fixed feature encoding, your proposed reinforcement learning approach with temporal difference learning (also as described in that article.) That would be a fair comparison of your proposed approach vs. temporal difference learning (as opposed to calling it a comparison against actual TD Gammon since you have little hope of replicating TD Gammon exactly anyway.)

You will probably see both methods improving as you add more features, and hopefully yours comes out on top in those comparisons.

Comment: Yes, I don't want any higher level features to be reflected in the board representation but rather a naive, raw board encoding. I think I was just a bit too obsessed with replicating Tesauro exactly :) Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 4):

I know, it's very old question but still I'd like to share

Encoding order is not important at all as you always sum all the inputs multiplied by weights. I was researching the topic and collected several encodings from someone's PhD thesis.

Sutton

```
case 0 => if (men >= 1) 1.0f else 0.0f
case 1 => if (men >= 2) 1.0f else 0.0f
case 2 => if (men >= 3) 1.0f else 0.0f
case 3 => if (men >= 4) (men - 3) / 2.0f else 0.0f
```

Tesauro89

```
case 0 => if (men == 1) 1.0f else 0.0f
case 1 => if (men == 2) 1.0f else 0.0f
case 2 => if (men == 3) 1.0f else 0.0f
case 3 => if (men >= 4) (men - 3) / 2.0f else 0.0f
```

Tesauro92

```
case 0 => if (men == 1) 1.0f else 0.0f
case 1 => if (men >= 2) 1.0f else 0.0f
case 2 => if (men == 3) 1.0f else 0.0f
case 3 => if (men >= 4) (men - 3) / 2.0f else 0.0f
```

GNU Backgammon

```
case 0 => if (men == 1) 1.0f else 0.0f
case 1 => if (men == 2) 1.0f else 0.0f
case 2 => if (men >= 3) 1.0f else 0.0f
case 3 => if (men >= 4) (men - 3) / 2.0f else 0.0f
```

I got position databases with precomputed equities for contact, crashed and race stages and run batch learning against them.

Sutton's encoding requires a lot more epochs, others converge significantly faster. Tesauro89 is the fastest in contact game stage, Tesauro92 in race stage. GnuBG encoding is in between Tesauro's encodings.

Also I tried different activation functions for hidden layer (40 hidden units): sigmoid, tanh, relu, leaking relu, extended elu, softrelu/softplus, symmetric elliott and log. Zero centered fuctions like tanh and symmetric elliott converge much faster than others. Again, faster means number of epochs, I didn't measure time. Very cheap relu might be a good choice. Training was stopped when networks were unable to improve any more. All networks eventually stopped at almost the same MSE. So my conclusion: implementation details are not that important.

Several years ago (maybe 10) Tesauro repeated TD-gammon training without all handcrafted features used before. Training rate was slow but as computers became faster, player with naive encoding matched more sophisticated player after reasonable time.

I tried also several more exotic functions but they didn't work at all.